# Adding an Incremental Div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is a button that adds a div and each div ID is incremented by 1. (I.E. 'rock0', 'rock1', 'rock2', etc.)

What the code is supposed to do is add a div with the ID 'rock', and then go through and find every div labeled 'rock' and change it to 'rock0', 'rock1', 'rock2', etc. However, right now all it does is add divs with the same ID without changing them.

I have a basic understanding of how auto-incrementating works, I just can't seem to combine it with adding a new div element. I'm almost positive there's a much easier way of doing it instead of the way I'm trying, but I'm unable to find that way after scouring the interwebs.

**My HTML:**

```
<button onClick="addRock()" style="padding: 10px;">Add Rock</button>
```

**My Javascript:**

```
var rocks = 1;
function addRock() {
    // This first line adds the new div with an ID of 'rock'
    document.getElementById('inventory').innerHTML += '<div class="item" id="rock" style="position: absolute; left: 10px;top: 10px;"> </div>';
    // These next few lines are supposed to go through and find any ID labeled 'rock'
    // and auto-increment each one by 1.
    var list = document.getElementById('rock');
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].setAttribute("id", "rock" + i);
}
    rocks++;
    $('#rocks').html('Rocks: ' + rocks);
    $( drag );
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! This is also my first question on Stack Overflow so if you need anymore information or something let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an *element* here:

```
var list = document.getElementById('rock');
```

But then trying to treat it like an *array* here:

```
list[i].setAttribute("id", "rock" + i);
```

Based on the description and the comments in the code, it sounds like you have *multiple elements* with the *same `id`*.  This is invalid markup, so the behavior of the JavaScript on that markup is going to be undefined.

But you probably don't need to have elements with the same `id` here.  Each button click adds a new rock, right?  And you have a global variable with the count.  So that function can just increment and add the new one, no need for a loop.  Something like this:

```
var rocks = 1;
function addRock() {
    // increment first or afterward, depending on what you want the id in the next line to be
    rocks++;

    // construct the id from the "rocks" variable
    document.getElementById('inventory').innerHTML +=
        '<div class="item" id="rock' + rocks + 
        '" style="position: absolute; left: 10px;top: 10px;"> </div>';

    // the rest of what you're doing
    $('#rocks').html('Rocks: ' + rocks);
    $(drag);
}
```

When you add a new element, add it with the correct `id`.  Instead of adding new elements with duplicate `id` values and then trying to correct them afterward.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to have fixed that problem, now I have others but I'm going to try to solve them on my own before I ask anymore questions I think.